# Why Am I Getting NaN (and not an answer)?

Tags: c#

I have this equation:

```
val2 = ((((((((((Math.Pow(((previous_val) + (val5*100)), 1.001)) / 24) / 60) / 60) * 100) / 3600)*h)/m)*s));
```

`previous_val` and `val5` are local variables that equal other values. The variables `h`, `m`, and `s` represent hours, minutes, and seconds.

My problem: When both, `m` and `s`, are equivalent to 0, I get a `NaN` Instead of my answer.
`NaN` was also achieved when `h` and `m` were equivalent to 0.

What should I add into my code that will throw an exception? I'm sure that the reason for this 'not a number' "error" is that I am dividing by zero.

Comment: You really should divide this into multiple lines.... `NaN` is `Not A Number`. `Not An Answer` would be `NaA`

Comment: Perhaps this is NaQ?

Comment: That's why I love comments xD

Comment: floating point division by `0` will not trigger an exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A NaN is easy to produce:

```
float f = 0.0f / 0; // NaN (note use of fp operand to promote / to fp)
float g = f + 42;   // NaN
```

How do/can the zeros in `h`, `m`, and `s` cause that? Remember, once a `NaN` has been introduced, it will silently propagate through in most cases. (As others have suggested, breaking the problem up into smaller bite-size portions will aide in debugging -- and likely future maintainability ;-)

While a final (or intermediate) `IsNaN` check will work to detect the scenario, consider checking/reacting to illegal inputs as well. (I am not sure if there is a way to get [the rare] *signaling NaN* in C#, which is different than the *quiet NaN* observed, but quick google searches say: not possible.)

Happy coding.

---

Although [standard] *floating point* operations will not throw an exception (as `NaN` *is encoded as a floating point value*), *integer* math operations may throw an exception (as `NaN` is not encoded). If the operations are such that integer math is sufficient then it can be used to "throw" an exception:

```
int zero = 0;      // to trick compiler
int k = 42 / zero; // KABOOM! (DivideByZeroException)
```

Answer (score 1):

Floating point operations do not throw exceptions. Divide by zero will obviously not result in a valid answer and so you should check for this scenario before making the calculation.

Answer (score -2):

1. Simplify this expression into multiple sub-expressions, if possible.
2. Wrap in a "try/catch (DivideByZeroException ex)" block, if possible.
3. Most important, do your aritmetic in "double" (or "float") space, if possible (e.g. "24.0" instead of "24").

Comment: Floating point operations do not throw exceptions so using a try/catch block will not help.